# Problems connecting to MS Dynamics AX 2009 Application Object Server

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-gp

I've got a funny problem connecting to an AOS server.

I got a domain network containing a (VM) Server running the Application Object Server (AOS).

Client computer A) can connect to the AOS without problems and work.

When client computer B) tries to connect, all I get is this error message:
*Logon Error*
*Connection with the Application Object Server could not be established.*

The event log of Client B) does not contain any messages about this.
Firewalls are off on all three computers (by GP).
Tcp/ip from cliebt B) to the AOS server does run fine.
Both clients run the same OS (win 7 RC), sit on the same subnet, next to each other.
Yesterday it all worked, today just one computer can connect.

Any ideas what might cause this problem, how to resolve it, or how to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Problem may be with stored credentials in Windows 7.

Clear appropriate credentials under: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the job. I've tried everything previously, from altering the configurations in the win registry, flushing dns, deleting auc files, altering the hosts file and even reinstalling the client but only clearing the credentials does the job. Regards,
Viktor

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me under Windows 7:

Control Panel >> Administrative Tools >> Services >> Search on " Dynamics Ax " and click " play Button " ( coloured Green ) in the tool bar ..

Should do the trick!

Comment: This would start the service, if it is not started?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for resurrecting a dead post, but did you ever find the root cause of this problem?

The first thing I would check would be that the Ax Client configuration Connection settings are correct.

The only time I've seen an error remotely close to what you describe on an AOS that is up and working is when users are not connecting with a shared client configuration file and the active configuration on the client throwing the error is identical in all respects save that of the AOS port number assignment.

For example:
AOS Server is configured on port 2712 (the default)

Client A -> Configured to connect to AOS on port 2712

Client B -> Configured to connect to AOS on port 2714

Comment: Nope, never found the root cause. Client configuration was good, though.